# ¿Se debe configurar php o apache para que tome los include?

Tags: php, apache

Estoy haciendo la migracion de una pagina a google cloud y ya tengo problemas con los certificados digitales y cargar fuentes o scripts externos.
Pero por algun motivo php tampoco me esta haciendo los includes en el codigo html.

Espero puedan ayudar. 
¡Saludos!

Comment: Está bastante amplia la pregunta: Lo de los certificados es configuración del servidor (si estás usando apache te podría ayudar). Lo de las fuentes externas y script lo mismo pero también puede ser configuración del VPS (¿ estás usando una instancia Linux? ). Lo de los include es rarísimo ¿ Estás usando algún framework como Slim, Laravel, Phalcon o estas usando PHP sin framework? Danos un poco más de datos para ayudarte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta es **No**.

Partiendo de una maquina **Ubuntu 18.04** recién instalada con la version de **Apache 2.4.29** y de **PHP 7.2.15** (Todo recién instalado, sin ningún componente más)

Se puede hacer una prueba muy básica. En el mismo directorio donde se encuentra el **index.php** (En este caso /var/www/php) se crea un fichero **Persona.php** cuyo contenido es el siguiente:

```php
<?php

class Persona{
        private $nombre;

        function __construct(string $nombre){
                $this->nombre = $nombre;
        }

        public function getNombre(){
                return  $this->nombre;
        }

}

?>
```

Una vez se tenga este fichero, el contenido del fichero **index.php** de prueba debe ser:

```php
<?php
include "Persona.php";

        $persona = new Persona("Gabriel");

        $nombre = $persona->getNombre();
        echo($nombre);

?>
```

Resultado en el navegador:
**Gabriel**

El resultado en el navegador es el propio nombre del objeto. En este caso "Gabriel", como se puede observar, el include ha funcionado sin necesidad de configurar nada más ni en PHP ni en Apache.

También obtendríamos el mismo resultado si en vez de `include "Persona.php";` fuera `require_once("Persona.php");`